# Page changes without loading the page

Tags: html

Does anyone know how to tell me how to change the page like the sites below?

https://numbered.studio/contact

https://5scontent.com/work/

https://www.cappen.com/about

Not a link? So there is no reload? Is it a framework that does this?
If there is no link, no problem? To make user browsing heavy?

Comment: That would be CSS, HTML, and JavaScript. There can be some AJAX, but can do it without it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided site maybe using any framework. But this can be possible using JS. I think the example of websites are single pages HTML template based on JS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would like to block the top of the site, making scrolling the page the top of the site is blocked. This section can definitely help you:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp

First create a `<div>`. After you have customized and entered the information, insert a block that can block `<div>`. Better if you also create a `<span>` block to define the affected area.